# Limit access to Google Cloud Platform Console

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to know if someone was able to put some security on Google Cloud Platform Console so users can only access to it from specific Mac address ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to limit the access to the Google Cloud Platform Console of your project in order that just some mac addresses can have access to it? or are you talking about some other service like GCE or GAE?

Comment: If your question is really about the console, you do realize that the platform is a common public interface?

Answer (score 1):

I know of now way to accomplish security restrictions to the Google Cloud Platform Console with Ethernet MAC addresses.

1. Attempting to use MAC addresseses is not a good security method. Almost every platform (OS) supports modifying the MAC address of a system. MAC addresses can be spoofed.
2. Google Cloud Platform uses OAuth 2.0 for authorization. Google's OAuth does not factor in MAC addresses for authorization.

I recommend that you implement MFA for your Google accounts if you desire very tight security. Look into [Google 2-Step Verification](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/) and [Google Authenticator](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1066447?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en).